# Meaning of residual vs. predicted quantile plots in DHARMa?

Tags: generalized-linear-model, predictive-models

I am fairly new to statistics and R and I need a bit of help to understand the results of my GLM. I am using bee species richness as the response variable and plant species richness as the predictor variable. I only have 12 data points and the data is not nd.

```r
m2 <- glm(Bee_SR ~ Plant.species.richness, data = IOP_pan, 
   family = "poisson")
summary (m2)
```

Can someone help me understand if my model is okay?

[image: summary (m2)]

[image: DHARMa 1]

[image: DHARMa 2]

Comment: What does "nd" mean?  Could you edit your question to include the data summary in a text format rather than as a screenshot?  It would also be somewhat useful to know the range of your response variable ...

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say for sure without more detail. The DHARMa residual-pattern plot (right-hand plot) strongly suggests that there's a non-(log)-linear pattern in the bee/plant species richness relationship. You should look at a plot of your raw data to confirm this suspicion (`plot(Bee_SR ~ Plant.species.richness, data = IOP_pan, log = "y")`) and try a quadratic model (`Bee_SR ~ poly(Plant.species.richness, 2)` ) to see if that helps resolve the problem.